# Assign a category from directory structure to a page in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I want to prepare a newsletter archive page, using the Jekyll and github pages. Each edition has several content categories. I however intend to use `pages` instead of `posts`, as all posts would have the same date. The page category should be set by folder structure.

My plan was to have each edition as a collection with subfolders, which would assign the category tag:

```
root
   \_edition1
      \cars
          \Skoda.md
          \Volvo.md
      \boats
          \BoatyMcBoatface.md
          \QueenElizabeth.md
  \_edition2
      \cars
          \Trabant.md
          \Volvo.md
      \boats
          \BoatyMcBoatface.md
          \LittleBoat.md
```

The question is, how to assign `category` by directory structure to `pages` in collection?

I suppose this is a common use case, however even [jekyll homepage](http://jekyllrb.com) use a workaround ([manually build index with custom categories in `_data` section](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/docs/_data/docs.yml)). Could this functionality be somewhat automatically generated by folder structure?

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: Check out this thread: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1819#issuecomment-89003858

Comment: However they deal with the _posts, whereas I am trying to do this with pages. Is it even doable? Thanks

Comment: You could read the page url and split on 'slash'.

Comment: What do you mean when you say posts would have the same date? Why does that prevent you from using posts instead of pages?